# Set QTabWidget Order by text of tabs

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to set tab order by tab text or tab name

```
    ui.tabWidget->setTabOrder(//set order here by tab name like "helloTab","hiTab");
    //I have tried this(I know it's dumb just trying)
    ui.tabWidget->setTabOrder(ui.tabWidget->tabBar->findChild<QTab *>("tab_1"), ui.tabWidget->tabBar->findChild<QTab *>("tab_2"));
```

Till now no hope of getting this done. I am fairly new to qt.
Any Ideas or help would be helpful.

Comment: `I have tried this` and what happened, and why is that wrong? it would also help to show your current tabs and how they're created, and identify what the correct order should be vs those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QTab is not defined in Qt. Use QWidget:

```
ui.tabWidget->setTabOrder(ui.tabWidget->tabBar->findChild<QWidget *>("tab_1"), ui.tabWidget->tabBar->findChild<QWidget *>("tab_2"));
```

Comment: I think it was defined in like version 2, but it's only seemingly available in archived docs now.